# trying to fill array but assignment isnt going through

Tags: java

here i am trying to add a value to the next open position in the array and then return true, and if there isnt any more open positions return false, im a bit lost here as i dont know why it isnt adding the value to the index position on the array.

```
public boolean add(String item) {
    for (int nextPos = 0; nextPos < bag.length; nextPos++) {
        if (bag[nextPos] == null) {
            item = bag[nextPos];
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

assume i am just filling in the explicit with a random string "x"
what do i have to do to make it add the item to the next slot in the array

update: before i posted this i tried many things in the test cases and no matter what they still returned true regardless if it went past the bag limit

```
public void testAdd() {

   stringBag filledBag = new stringBag(10);
   assertNotNull(filledBag);
   filledBag.add("next");
   filledBag.add("thing");
   assertEquals(true, filledBag.add("test"));
   stringBag fullBag = new stringBag(3);
   fullBag.add("new");
   fullBag.add("new");
   fullBag.add("new");
   fullBag.add("new");
   assertEquals(false, fullBag.add("newOne"));

}
```

so here i assume its reading them as null for the empty slots but its just not assigning them and going straight to true, what is needed to fix this?

update! okay i feel like big dumb, thanks for pointing out that error that i could not find, i guess i was blowing this out of proportion and thought it wa s a bigger problem

this is resolved thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've made a simple mistake. Assignment places the value on the right side of the = into the variable on the left side. In your case you are storing the contents of bag at nextPos into item (essentially overwriting it to null).

```java
item = bag[nextPos];
```

What you meant to do was store item into bag at nextPos.

```java
bag[nextPos] = item;
```